# oneway binding from DOM to component variable

Tags: angular, data-binding

Angular provides several ways to bind variables to DOM properties. You can use `{{}}` syntax, `[property]=expression` or two-way ngModel binding.

I haven't found a way to do the reverse: bind DOM to the component variables. For example: how do you bind elements width to the `width` property declared in `component.ts` file. The only data flow from DOM to component I am aware are events.

Comment: As opposite to AngularJS, Angular doesn't provide a way two-way data binding anymore. Only in the case of forms and `ngModel` you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator for accessing native DOM element of your choice. There you can find properties like `width`, you can either read them, or update them. For updating it is recommended to use `Renderer2` service (main difference is that is supports server side rendering I guess).

```
export class MyComponent { 

      @ViewChild('myReference') el: ElementRef;

      doSomething() {
          console.log(el.nativeElement.width); // 350
      }

}

<div #myReference style="width: 350px"></div>
```

More about this here:

https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/

Answer (score 0):

Use [Style Binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#style-binding) to bind *height*, *width*, etc.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make myself clear enough. I do not want to set the style. I want to bind style value to variable in component. Direction is important here. from DOM to component and not the other way around.